# Attempting to echo with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to go from mySQL (about time?) to PDO - but I am having trouble in making sense of how things are supposed to be written. I want to be protected from injection, but I just can't figure out how to do it properly. It just seems so confusing. It might be because I'm doing it COMPLETELY wrong?

Been looking around for help on various sides doing tutorials, but :(

Any chance someone could assist me? Explain/show like I'm five?

```
<?php
$col_playername = "playername";
$tbl_playerdata = "player_data";
$post_search = "$_POST[search]";

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT :col_playername FROM :tbl_playerdata
                WHERE :col_playername LIKE %:post_search%
                LIMIT 5");

$sth->bindParam(":col_playername", $col_playername);
$sth->bindParam(":tbl_playerdata", $tbl_playerdata);
$sth->bindParam(":post_search", $post_search);  

$sth->execute();

foreach ($sth as $row)
{
    ?>
    <div id="search_show">
        <a href="?target=<?php echo $row["playername"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["playername"]; ?></a> 
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

As of right now - nothing is coming out. I wouldn't be surprised if this is absolutely wrong.

Comment: You can learn here: http://php.net/pdo

Comment: FYI, the simple operation of using prepared statements helps cut down on SQL injection attacks when compared to regular statements, so you are already on the right path.  For extra protection, make sure that every query that has parameters is prepared.  Even SELECT statements that don't have user input in them could have information previously injected into them to help an attacker engage in a [second-order attack](http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/html/lesson1/les01_tm_attacks.htm)

Comment: You can't bind tables and columns. You also need to change `$post_search = "$_POST[search]";` to `$post_search = $_POST['search'];` and this may be invalid `LIKE %:post_search%`

Answer (score 1):

`$statement->execute()` will execute, but not fetch your rows.

You need to add either `$statement->fetch()` to get one result set, or `$statement->fetchAll` to get an array:

```
$sth->execute();

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Note: Since you are handling your results as associative arrays, you should this *before preparing* anything. It will save you from specifying the fetch mode with every single `fetch()`.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```